# how to develop much Jsonarray

Tags: java, json

How can I make one data use one JSONarray? Currently I am using one JSONARRAY only. Please find code below and suggest.

```
public class test {
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
    "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
public JSONArray generateData(String idDevice, Date startTime, Date
dateTime, Date endTime) {
   JSONArray arrBuff = new JSONArray();
    try {
        for (long i = startTime.getTime(); i <= endTime.getTime(); i += 1000) {
            //for (int l=0;i<l;l++){
            arrBuff.add("idDevice:\"" + idDevice + "\"");
            arrBuff.add("dateTime:\"" + dateFormat.format(new Date(i)) +
                "\"");
            arrBuff.add("dateType: HRM");
            arrBuff.add("ValueUnit:bpm");
            i++;
        }
        System.out.println("Successfully Copied JSON Object to 
          File...");
        System.out.println("\nJSON Object: " + arrBuff);

        return arrBuff;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return arrBuff;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me which language you are using? .net? Please tag your question to get a better answer

Comment: i use java to develop

Comment: Please retag your question with the correct language, you will get a better answer faster/

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish? Why do you need multiple json arrays?